# Sorting a column by an int in Entity Framework 6 Code First using MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have started learning c# and MVC and I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application). In the tutorial, they have the option to sort a column either ascending or descending but it is a string. In my code, I have a different column I want to sort and it is an int. If I sort string numbers, eg '1,3,22,2', it'll give me '1,2,22,3'.

I'm not too sure what code would be useful to put here but here is my current index method in the controller which is sorting the column by strings at the moment (it includes some code for paging but that is working fine :L)

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
        ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";

        if (searchString != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            searchString = currentFilter;
        }

        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

        var utilities = from s in db.Utilities
                       select s;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            utilities = utilities.Where(s => s.WeekNo.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
        }

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "name_desc":
                utilities = utilities.OrderByDescending(s => s.WeekNo);
                break;
            default:
                utilities = utilities.OrderBy(s => s.WeekNo);
                break;
        }

        int pageSize = 2;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return View(utilities.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));

    }
```

I try to convert the index like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, int searchNo, int? page)
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
        ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";

        if (searchNo != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        //else
        //{
          //  searchString = currentFilter;
        //}

        //ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

        var utilities = from s in db.Utilities
                       select s;
        if (searchNo != null)
        {
            utilities = utilities.Where(s => s.WeekNo == searchNo);
        }

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "name_desc":
                utilities = utilities.OrderByDescending(s => s.WeekNo);
                break;
            default:
                utilities = utilities.OrderBy(s => s.WeekNo);
                break;
        }

        int pageSize = 2;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return View(utilities.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));

    }
```

and when I run it, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snUHN.jpg)

Comment: `OrderBy`/`OrderByDescending` will work perfectly fine with `int`. What issue are you having?

Comment: I edited the question as it was too long to reply here.

Comment: That error is related to the fact you are passing a `null` value (or omitting) the `searchNo` parameter, this has nothing to do with querying. How are you building the URL?

Comment: Omitting it where? 
Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by building the URL. It is all done locally and it runs in IE. Sorry again, I'm a big noob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `searchNo` paramter appears to be optional but your action signature dictates that it *has* to be provided. Update `searchNo` to be a nullable and your problem should disappear

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, int? searchNo, int? page)
{
    page = searchNo.HasValue ? 1 : page;
    ...
    if (searchNo.HasValue)
    {
        utilities = utilities.Where(s => s.WeekNo == searchNo.Value);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: It works now :D I see what you mean by optional parameter. Thank you so much :)

Comment: The code I commented out in the second block of code `searchNo = currentFilter;` is stopping the search from working, any way of working around it? I tried converting searchNo to string just to see if it'd work but it doesn't.

Comment: If you need `ViewBag.CurrentFilter` set...then set it. You seem to pass `currentFilter` as a parameter therefore I presume you would just want to do `ViewBag.CurrentFilter = currentFilter`.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it after I asked. I was being silly and forgot to change the last `searchString`. Thank you again though. you've been a great help.

Comment: @Calturk you should accept/upvote this answer if it solved your problem, this helps future visitors.

Comment: Oh sorry. I tried upvoting it at the time but that requires 15 reputation. I didn't know about the green tick. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If it is guaranteed that the "string numbers" you spoke of are integers, then why not type them as such? If they have to always be strings, then I would cast them as integers and use OrderBy() or OrderByDecending(). If they absolutely MUST be strings, then you will need to write a class that implements [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), then in the compare method you will do your comparison there, IE. casting the items to integers then saying `x < y`. Then you will feed that into a Sort method on the list.

Comment: They don't have to be strings, the tutorial just shows you how to sort a column that has strings. I'm following the tutorial with my own table and I want a int column instead.